# Material UI component is losing styles inside react-frame-component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement Persistent drawer, available in the demo code in Material UI V3. Link is below
https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/drawers/#persistent-drawer

I am wrapping it inside react-frame-component, as I want it as a different iframe.
When I am trying to do it, it renders the demo code, but it loses all the Material UI styles.

Code is as below

In PersistentDrawerLeft.jsx
(Code is copied from the link given above)

In MainFile.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Frame from "react-frame-component";
import PersistentDrawerLeft from "./PersistentDrawerLeft.jsx";

const MainFile = () => {
  
  return (
    <Frame>
        <PersistentDrawerLeft />
    </Frame>
    )
}

export default MainFile;
```

Could someone please help me out in this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question. Or share either stackblitz or code sandbox. So we can give a good solution.

Comment: Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-frame-component-with-material-ui-8hsiz

Answer (score 6):

I have just been experiencing the same issue with a current project but I am using the latest versions. My solution is to use the `FrameContextConsumer` and inject the `jss` inside the callback. This example is also defining a new material theme that is distinct from the theme of the frame's parent, you may not need that for your usage.

Here is the link to my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-frame-component-with-material-ui-6tqg5

An important consideration to make is when using any Material UI component that has a `Modal` as a parent (which is quite a few components, including a variant of a `Drawer`). In my example, I have added a `Button` that opens a `Dialog` and on the `Dialog` the `disablePortal` property is included. This will ensure the `Dialog` opens in the frame rather than in the parent where all styles are lost since they were injected into the frame.

```
import React from "react";
import { create } from "jss";
import { jssPreset } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { ThemeProvider, StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Frame, { FrameContextConsumer } from "react-frame-component";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#556cd6"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#19857b"
    },
    background: {
      default: "#dedede",
      paper: "#ffffff"
    }
  }
});

const CustomHead = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <meta charSet="utf-8" />
      <title>Previewer</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
      <base target="_parent" />
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
      />
    </>
  );
};

const PreviewFrame = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Frame frameBorder={0} {...props} head={<CustomHead />}>
      <FrameContextConsumer>
        {({ document, window }) => {
          const jss = create({
            plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins],
            insertionPoint: document.head
          });
          return (
            <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
              <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
            </StylesProvider>
          );
        }}
      </FrameContextConsumer>
    </Frame>
  );
};

export default PreviewFrame;
```

Comment: This is the first thing I've found that addresses the issue!! I've looked everywhere. Thank you so much. disablePortal was the missing element for me.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I have come up with a solution to the problem.

The Problem is,

Every iframe has its own context. The context has its own session history and document. The browsing context that embeds the others is called the parent browsing context which is the browser `window` object.

The Material UI Style provider can only provide the styles for parent context. So we have to inject the style provider to the iframe context.

The solution is,

The Material UI itself we have a solution for it.
The [DemoFrame.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v3.x/docs/src/modules/components/DemoFrame.js) is actually injected the StyleProvider to the IFrame context.

Please find the working example in [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-on-iframe-dhh9c).

*If anybody knows any other better solution. Please suggest in the comment section.*

Comment: I tried this approach and I am getting error at below line in DemoFrame
`this.contentDocument = ref ? ref.node.contentDocument : null;`

Error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'contentDocument' of undefined`

Comment: Please let me know the versions of react, material UI, react-frame-component. Because I was used latest versions.

Comment: react - 16.11.0, @material-ui/core - 3.9.3,react-frame-component - 4.1.1

Comment: Is possible to upgrade the material UI version?

Comment: However, I have updated the versions that you have mentioned above.  Please refer to the same code sandbox URL. But, I will like to recommend to use the latest version of the Material UI.

Comment: Unfortunately its not possible to update the version, as there are many dependencies associated with the current version. But, I went with the traditional approach of not using iframe, making some CSS changes and adding JavaScript logic and it worked!!!...Thanks a lot for your efforts int this...Really appreciate..